# Rails Heroku change column data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I run this command for deploying database to heroku

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

But I got this error

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "dateti" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activated_at" dateti
                                               ^
```

After that I changed wrong datatype "dateti" to "datetime"

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

But nothing changed. Still get this error. For development and test I use sqlite3 and for production postgresql. This error appear only when I try to deploy to heroku. On local database everything works.

database.yml file

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem "sqlite3"
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: sample_app_production
  username: sample_app
  password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before change  `activited_at (datetime)` in `AddActivationToUsers` file. You must rollback AddActivationToUsers in db.

1. rails db:rollback STEP=n (`n` migrations where n is the number of recent migrations you want to rollback)
2. You change `activited_at :datetime` and save
3. rails db:migration